# how to search file?

Tags: javascript, node.js, ajax

So I want to be able to search a CSV file stored on the internet (google drive or google storage bucket) using a key, the CSV file will store a list of names and email addresses.

I need the function to search the CSV file using the name and find the corresponding email address and then store that email address in a variable so I can use it later on.

**CSV File Format:**

```
Project Name:               Email:
example-project-sandbox example@example.com
```

I have a non working attempt at this however I think this is a bit long winded and can be done a lot simpler.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "https://storage.googleapis.com/file.csv",
    dataType: "text",
    success: function(data) {
      processData(data);
    }
  });
});

function processData(allText) {
  var allTextLines = allText.split(/\r\n|\n/);
  var headers = allTextLines[0].split(',');
  var lines = [];

  for (var i = 1; i < allTextLines.length; i++) {
    var data = allTextLines[i].split(',');

    if (data.length == headers.length) {
      var tarr = [];

      for (var j = 0; j < headers.length; j++) {
        tarr.push(headers[j] + ":" + data[j]);
      }
      lines.push(tarr);
    }
  }
  // alert(lines);
}
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please show your latest non-working attempt at solving this problem. It is usually more instructive to see fixes to your code than to read someone else's solution. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @Spangen Please see updated thread.

Comment: Nice one, hopefully that will be enough to get you a good answer

Comment: All you need to do now is loop once through `tarr` and save the line that contains "whatever-project" in a variable (`tarr[x]['Project Name']`). Then `tarr[x]['Email']` should contain what you need.

Comment: @SergiuParaschiv Can you show a code example if possible please, as i'm not 100%, Also my current code doesn't search using a key i want to search for the name and then it give me and save in a variable the email corresponding to that name

Answer (score 0):

Use this library.It will really help parsing the file and save time.

[Papaparse](https://www.papaparse.com/)

It's very easy check this example.

```
// Parse CSV string
var data = Papa.parse(csv);

// Convert back to CSV
var csv = Papa.unparse(data);

// Parse local CSV file
Papa.parse(file, {
complete: function(results) {
    console.log("Email:", results.email);
}
});
```

If helped marked the answer and completed. :D

Answer (score 0):

1) Change `tarr.push(headers[j]+":"+data[j]);` to `tarr.push({name: headers[j], email: data[j]});`

2) Loop through `tarr` and search for `"whatever-name"``:

```
var foundEmail;

for (var i = 0; i < tarr.length; i++) {
    if (tarr[i].name === "whatever-name") {
        foundEmail = tarr[i].email;
        break;  
    }
}

console.log(foundEmail);
```